# Unlisted facebook connect app

Tags: facebook, settings, facebook-apps

How do I make my facebook connect app unlisted? I don't want people to be able to search facebook for an app and find my facebook connect app.  But I don't want to use sandbox mode as anybody that comes to my site needs to be able to use the facebook connect app.

Thanks,
Brendan